# como hago para que me funcionen estos if statement?

Tags: python, if, function

Lo que pasa es que cuando corro my programa, el output me repite las preguntas mas de lo normal.(a veces 4 veces aveces 2 o 1).

mi error sea talvez por que llamo a las funciones muchas veces o por que hago mal uso del if statement pero no estoy seguro. me pueden sacar de la duda?gracias de antemano.

```
def respuesta_pc():
  compu_respuesta = input('esta es la respuesta de la computadora:')
  return compu_respuesta

def respuesta_humana():
  huma_respuesta = input('esta es tu respuesta')
  return huma_respuesta

if  respuesta_pc()== 'roca' and  respuesta_humana() == 'papel' :
  print('el papel le gana a la roca.tu ganas')
elif respuesta_pc() == 'roca' and  respuesta_humana() == 'tijera' :
  print('la roca le gana a la tijera. tu pierdes')
elif respuesta_pc() == 'roca' and  respuesta_humana() == 'roca' :
  print('es empate')
else:
  print('tu respuesta no es valida')
```

El programa recien lo estoy comenzando por eso estoy probando las respuestas con roca.

Respuesta de pc=roca

Tu respuesta= (la que quieras)

Comment: Deberías hacerlo mas eficiente y no ejecutar la función en cada IF, antes de entrar a los if crea 2 variables, r_pc y r_hum, ahí guardas el resultado de las respectivas funciones, y cuando entras al if solo evalúas las variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás llamando a las funciones cada vez que pasas por un `if` y por eso piden más datos de la cuenta. Si no es necesario, las llamadas a las funciones se hacen una vez y el valor retornado se asigna a una variable.

Por otro lado, faltan más opciones en la comparación:

```
roca - papel
roca - tijera
papel - roca
papel - tijera
tijera - roca
tijera - papel
- cuando son iguales -
```

Teniendo eso en cuenta, el código puede quedar en algo parecido a esto:

```
def respuesta_pc():
    compu_respuesta = input('Esta es la respuesta de la computadora: ')
    return compu_respuesta

def respuesta_humana():
    huma_respuesta = input('Esta es tu respuesta: ')
    return huma_respuesta

resp_pc = respuesta_pc()
resp_hm = respuesta_humana()
opciones = ['roca', 'papel', 'tijera']

if resp_pc not in opciones:
    print('La respuesta de la computadora no es valida')
elif resp_hm not in opciones:
    print('Tu respuesta no es valida')
elif resp_pc == 'roca' and resp_hm == 'papel' :
    print('El papel le gana a la roca. Tu ganas')
elif resp_pc == 'roca' and resp_hm == 'tijera' :
    print('La roca le gana a la tijera. Tu pierdes')
elif resp_pc == 'papel' and resp_hm == 'roca' :
    print('El papel le gana a la roca. Tu pierdes')
elif resp_pc == 'papel' and resp_hm == 'tijera' :
    print('La tijera le gana al papel. Tu Ganas')
elif resp_pc == 'tijera' and resp_hm == 'roca' :
    print('La roca le gana a la tijera. Tu Ganas')
elif resp_pc == 'tijera' and resp_hm == 'papel' :
    print('La tijera le gana al papel. Tu pierdes')
else:
    print('Es empate')
```

Comment: muchas gracias .